# How to merge every two columns, with pandas, substituting only if the left column value is nan or 0

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2n columns and each pair looks like this:

```
1   0
2   0
45  1
44  10
43  22
0   55
0   46
0   75
```

I want to turn each pair of columns into a single one where the 0 or NaN of the left column are substituted by the values on the right column.
In this example the result would be

```
1
2
45
44
43
55
46
75
```

And it is important that this is done for every pair of columns in the dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d = {'col1': [1,2,45,44,43,0,0,0,2],
     'col2': [0,0,1,10,22,55,46,75,np.nan],
      }

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df=df.replace(np.nan,0)
df['col2']=np.where(df['col1']==0,df['col2'],df['col1'])
```

Comment: OBS.: ```import numpy as np```

Comment: col2 is exactly the output expecting I think

Comment: I confused, I thought he wanted to replace and put in column 1, sorry for the confusion =)

Comment: that works if I have only two columns
I want to do that to every pair of columns in the df

Comment: @rdlc7 so you put in a function and giving as argument, which columns you are using and where do you want to store the result no ?

Answer (score 0):

First, a dataframe is created from the dictionary. Then all 0 are replaced by `np.nan`. This has the advantage that you can use the `fillna()` function afterwards to replace all `np.nan` values with the corresponding value from `col2`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy  as np

d = {'col1': [0,0,1,10,22,55,46,34,np.nan],
     'col2': [1,2,45,44,43,0,0,0,2]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df.replace(0, np.nan, inplace=True)
df['col1'].fillna(df['col2']).to_frame()
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?